# Increase the label name

Tags: c#, foreach, label

I need a command code that increase the `label name`.

I need to display in 10 (example) `labels` some texts.

Example:

```
label1.Text = "1";
label2.Text = "2";
label3.Text = "3";
label4.Text = "4";
label5.Text = "5";
label6.Text = "6";
```

I need to increase the number from `label name (label1, label2, etc.)` in a `foreach` where I will increase the variable `i` (`i` will be use in a structure like this `label.Name = "label" + i.ToString();`).

I hope that you understand what I want to say.

I try this but don't work:

```
Label[] label = new Label[2];

int ii = 0;
foreach(...) // go through a list
{
                label[ii] = new Label();
                label[ii].Text = x.materie + tip + "\nsala " + x.sala;
                label[ii].Visible = true;
                label[ii].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(cX, cY);
                label[ii].SetBounds(cX, cY, 98, cH);
                label[ii].MinimumSize = new Size(98, cH);
                label[ii].MaximumSize = new Size(98, cH);

                ii++;
}
```

Comment: don't understand much, you know the answer, what is your point in here?

Comment: That is not the answer. I only display the label.Name structure, but not the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an array of Label controls, label, you can do the following:

```
int i = 1;

for (int i = 1; i < label.Length; i++)
{
    lbl.ID = String.Format("label{0}", i.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I have this: Label[] label = new Label[50];, but how I can built the LabelCollection ?

Comment: You can even use the array even instead of collection (if you don't have). Check my updated answer :)

Comment: I try a method that I display in the question (edit the questio). Why don't work ?

Answer (score 3):

```
int count = 10;
for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
{
    // setup label and add them to the page hierarchy
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Name = "label" + i;
    lbl.Text = i.ToString();
    //assuming form1 is a form in your page with a runat="server" attribute.
    this.Controls.Add(lbl); 
}
```

Comment: Say that label don't contain a definition for ID and don't found the MyParentControl command.

Comment: @AnDr3yy You do not need to add MyParentControl since you do not have a container with this name. Please try to add "this" instead of "MyParentControl" so it'd look like this: this.Controls.Add(lbl);

Comment: MyParentControl is your form or some panel where you want to put labels. Replace it with: Form1.Controls.Add(lbl);

Comment: This function is in a public static function that is in a class. Don't work this becouse is not a static field initializer. And the ID don't work.

Comment: @Kamil I try to add the code in Form1 and I put: Form1.Controls.Add(lbl); - but error.